# Maven repository toolkit - Synchronise, verify, delete, verbose info about artifact (local repository), check pgp, uninstall

Tags: maven, repository, command-line-interface

I've tried and failed to find an easy way to control my local repository and to work with remote repositories.
I don't think, I need whole repository management tool (such as Nexus or Artifactory) to do simple tasks, such as:

- List locally installed artifacts
- Show informations about artifact from repository (both local and remote)
- Verify PGP signatures for artifact (locally after fetching the artifact, or remotely if possible)
- Download artifacts by selector into local repository (can be `mvn dependency:get`)
- Download artifacts javadoc/source into local repository
- Verify availability of either sources or javadocs
- Remove locally installed artifact by selector (either shorthanded gradle or longer mvn cli type)

Every single clue I've found was linked to specific build-script/system (ivy,grape,pom,gradle, ..), and I don't think I should have to create dummy project or directly touch files in repository manually.

If you come up with suggestions, I use unix-based platform and primarily CLI, but suggestions are welcomed for all platforms and UI variants.

Comment: Removing locally installed artifacts can be done by: `http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html`. The question is why do you need to list locally installed artifacts? If it's not there it will be downloaded. The pgp verification can be done with Nexus Pro version.  What kind of information about an artifact do you need?

Comment: @khmarbaise regarding the list of installed, is simply maintenance question, as I'd like to see what artifacts and versions my repository contains (also for snapshots), regarding the info about artifact, if you'll look on standard central repository pom file, there is lot of info, I'd like to have them probably in a way `apt-get`/`apt-cache` does it

Comment: The simplest solution is to install a repository manager and use it as a reference.

Comment: @khmarbaise and that's what I'm curious about, is it really necessary to have full repository manager, if the only thing I do is to work locally and deploy to remote repositories ? It really seems like a huge space and configuration overhead to me.